# Как добавить в список значения из списка словарей по ключу при помощи map?

Tags: python, list, словари, map

Есть словарь :

```
    contacts = [{'name': 'Allen Raymond', 'email': 'nulla.ante@vestibul.co.uk', 'phone': '(992) 914-3792', 'favorite': False},
            {'name': 'Chaim Lewis', 'email': 'dui.in@egetlacus.ca', 'phone': '(294) 840-6685', 'favorite': False},
            {'name': 'Kennedy Lane', 'email': 'mattis.Cras@nonenimMauris.net', 'phone': '(542) 451-7038', 'favorite': False},
            {'name': 'Wylie Pope', 'email': 'est@utquamvel.net', 'phone': '(692) 802-2949', 'favorite': False},
            {'name': 'Cyrus Jackson', 'email': 'nibh@semsempererat.com', 'phone': '(501) 472-5218', 'favorite': False}
            ]
```

Функция принимает список словарей и должна возвращать только список email'ов пользователей.

```
def get_emails(list_contacts):
emails = []
map(emails.append(list_contacts['email']), list_contacts)
return emails
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `def get_emails(list_contacts):  return [x['email'] for x in list_contacts]`

Comment: А при помощи map как это сделать?

Comment: `return list(map(lambda x: x['email'], list_contacts))`

Comment: Все работает, а расскажи пожалуйста как это работает и что я делал не так? Почему мой вариант не работал.

Comment: почитайте хотя бы синтаксис вызова map, я думаю, большая часть вопросов получит ответы

Comment: `map` принимает на вход функцию и какой-то итерируемый объект. Возвращает итератор, который состоит из элементов полученных из элементов исходного объекта, к каждому из которых применили функцию. Исходный итерируемый объект никак не модифицируется. Что у вас не так: 1 - к списку обращаетесь как будто это словарь (из-за чего вылетает ошибка), 2 - передаете не функцию первым аргументом, а пытаетесь передать туда результат вызова append (который `None`), 3 - никак не используете то что вернула функция map.